# Laravel 6: How to override sendPasswordResetNotification function

Tags: laravel, reset-password

I've been working on resetting password but using a custom notification instead of Laravel notification. This is the file `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword.php`

```
 public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
    //use custom notification to change the url instead of modifying the original class
    //$this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
    $this->notify(new CustomResetPassword($token));
}
```

That's ow I call it in a service class

```
$reset_password_status = Password::reset($credentials, function ($user, $password) {
    $user->password = $password;
    $user->save();
});

if ($reset_password_status == Password::INVALID_TOKEN) {
    return $this->returnError->error("Invalid token provided");
}
```

But the problem is building the project online is done automatically and run composer install every time and can't just upload the change manually so I'm looking for a way to override this function in my code to reset the password instead of editing `CanResetPassword.php` file which exists in the vendor folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your `Class` that is using this trait you can override this function. Every function written in class have priority over trait function.

Comment: I just updated the code by adding the call to the password reset. How can I modify it to use the custom notification here?

Comment: Thanks for the hint I managed to override it

Comment: If you resolve your problem please accept answer, I'll  be greatfull

Answer (score 0):

In `user.php` model

```
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
    $this->notify(new CustomResetPassword($token));
}
```

Comment: How to set ```$token```?